# Correctly join 1:n:1:1 relation in mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I'm developing a system to manage rental processes right now and I'm wondering how to efficiently query all rentable objects with the person name, who is currently renting it, if the object is rented at the moment. Otherwise there should be NULL in that column.

My tables look like:

**object**

```
 | object_id | object_name | 
 ---------------------------
 | 1         | Object A    | 
 | 2         | Object B    | 
 | 3         | Object C    | 
 | 4         | Object D    | 
 | 5         | Object E    | 
 ---------------------------
```

**person**

```
 | person_id | person_name | 
 ---------------------------
 | 1         | John Doe    | 
 | 2         | Jane Doe    | 
 | 3         | Max Muster  | 
 | 4         | Foobar      | 
 ---------------------------
```

**rental**

```
 | rental_id | rental_state| person_person_id | 
 ----------------------------------------------
 | 1         | open        | 1                |
 | 2         | returned    | 1                |
 | 3         | returned    | 2                |
 | 4         | open        | 3                |
 | 5         | returned    | 4                |
 ----------------------------------------------
```

**rental2object**

```
 | rental_rental_id | object_object_id | 
 ---------------------------------------
 | 1                | 1                | 
 | 2                | 2                | 
 | 2                | 3                |
 | 3                | 3                | 
 | 4                | 2                |
 | 4                | 5                |
 | 5                | 2                |
 ---------------------------------------
```

The result I want should look like this:

```
 | object_id | object_name | rented_to     |
 -------------------------------------------
 | 1         | Object A    | John Doe      |
 | 2         | Object B    | Max Muster    |
 | 3         | Object C    | NULL          |
 | 4         | Object D    | NULL          |
 | 5         | Object E    | Max Muster    |
 -------------------------------------------
```

What I've got so far is:

```
SELECT `object_id`, `object_name`, `person_name` FROM `object`
LEFT JOIN `rental2object` ON `object_id` = `object_object_id`
LEFT JOIN `rental` ON `rental_id` = `rental_rental_id` AND `rental_state` = 'open'
LEFT JOIN `person` ON `person_id` = `person_person_id`
GROUP BY `object_id`
```

The obvious problem is that I don't know how to aggregate the right way while grouping.

What would be the most efficient way to achieve my goal? Appreciate your help.

**EDIT**

Corrected the expected result, so that Object B is also rented to Max Muster.

Comment: There are columns in your `SELECT` statement that doesn't exists in `GROUP BY`.

Comment: objects #2 and #5 are both in rental #4. But you handle both in different way on your expected results. Object E and Object B both should be the same behaviour, both related witj Max Muster, it'snt? Why Object B has a Null related_to person?

Comment: Ok, I see your edit, then check my answer, is voted down from some muggle I don't know why.

Comment: By the way, thanks about this detailed question, I wrote a [database design exercise](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=ca&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=https%3A%2F%2Fuf.ctrl-alt-d.net%2Fmaterial%2Fmostra%2F268%2Fentitat-inter-relacio-exercicis-inter-relacions-representacio-grafica-ii&edit-text=&act=url) based on it. My students will hate you ... or appreciate. ;)

Comment: Thanks for your appreciation

Comment: Remove the `LEFTs` -- see how it works.  And remove the `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## About your question

Objects #2 and #5 are both in rental #4. But, on your expected results, you are handling both in different way. Object E and Object B both should be the same behaviour because they are in the same rental. If not, you should to explain witch is the criteria to know if a product has or not a related person.

## Group by

To be **SQL92** compliant you should to include in select clause all nonaggregated columns:

```
SELECT `object_id`, `object_name`, `person_name` as rented_to
FROM `object`
...
GROUP BY `object_id`, `object_name`, `person_name`
```

To be **SQL99** compliant you should to include in select clause all nonaggregated columns non functionlly dependent, in your case, they are a dependent between object_id and object_name: `object_id -> object_name` (the field *rental_state* breaks dependent functionality to *person*), then you can just to write:

```
SELECT `object_id`, `object_name`, `person_name` as rented_to
FROM `object`
...
GROUP BY `object_id`, `person_name`
```

MySQL 5.7.5 and up implements detection of functional dependence, then this last select is valid but I suggest to you that, for readability, use the first one.

Read [MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) for more info and `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` parameter details.

## Performance

Be sure you have indexes for:

- **object**: Object_id ( is primary key, then index is implicit )
- **rental2object**: object_object_id ( may be a composite index with the other field, but be sure object_object_id is the first field on index )
- **rental** : rental_id & rental_state ( a composite index with both fields )
- **person**: person_id ( is primary key, then index is implicit )

Comment: Look again query does not match desired output

Comment: I think based on the expected result that the last status for object b is returned but OPs solution thinks this is open and rented to Max Muster. Query probably needs a where in max test to find the last status for the object and shouldn't be testing for open in on clause.

Comment: Thank you for making me aware of the group by handling. After reading the relvant articles I think this might be what I'm looking for: `SELECT object_id, object_name, MAX(person_name) as rented_to FROM object LEFT JOIN rental2object ON object_id = object_object_id LEFT JOIN rental ON rental_id = rental_rental_id AND rental_state = 'open' LEFT JOIN person ON person_id = person_person_id GROUP BY object_id`

Comment: But is `MAX()` appropriate for that case?

Comment: Only has sense if a object may be in more than one opened rent at a time.  Unfortunately mysql has not ranking functions to get the last user over a partition. I think you may be interested on something like [Window Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/tutorial-window.html)  (but this functions are only available on SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL. Not in MySQL)

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
SELECT
    o.object_id,
    o.object_name,
    p.person_name AS rent_to
FROM
    rental2object ro
RIGHT JOIN object o ON ro.object_object_id = o.object_id
LEFT JOIN rental r ON ro.rental_rental_id = r.rental_id AND r.rental_status = 'open'
JOIN person p ON r.person_person_id = p.person_id
```

Comment: is not right, join to object should be a `right outer join` to select all objects.

Comment: I voted down because the issue is not on `from clause` also your approach was wrong. I remove the vote but think about it.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT      `object_id`, `object_name`, 
                case 
                    when rental_state = 'Open' then `person_name`
                    when r1.rental_rental_id is null then null
                else `rental_state`
                end  as RentedTo
FROM            `object`
LEFT JOIN   `rental2object` r1 ON `object_id` = r1.`object_object_id`
LEFT JOIN   `rental`                 ON `rental_id` = r1.`rental_rental_id` 
LEFT JOIN   `person`                 ON `person_id` = `person_person_id`
where           r1.rental_rental_id = 
                (select max(r2.`rental_rental_id`) 
                    from `rental2object` r2 
                    where r2.`object_object_id` = r1.`object_object_id`
                    group by r2.`object_object_id`) 
                or r1.rental_rental_id is null
GROUP BY    `object_id`;
```